# Add text to video using FFMPEG(c# application)

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

Trying to add text to video using FFMPEG via c# script using the following command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf drawtext="\text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: x=w-tw-10:y=h-th-10" -codec:a copy output.mp4
```

This works when run it from cmd but when I implement it here:

```
    public void AddNewLabel(string label)
    {
        //string video = "input.mp4";
        string filter = "input.mp4 -vf drawtext=\"\text='sampletext': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black: x=w-tw-10:y=h-th-10\"";//problemm is this line

        string args = $"/c ffmpeg -i {filter} -codec:a copy output.mp4";

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            WorkingDirectory = outputpath,
            Arguments = args
        };

        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
```

The output is a 0kb mp4 file that cant be opened. When i remove everything after input.mp4 in filter, the output is fine. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You appear to be starting a command shell (cmd.exe), just to run ffmpeg.  Why not just run ffmpeg instead?

Comment: My assignment requires me to create a c# application where the user can input text into a list and have it added to the corner of the selected video. I can do it if I run ffmpeg from the command line but i need it to work via the c# app.

Comment: What I mean is, why not use 'ffmpeg' as the `FileName` and `args` as the Arguments property ?

Comment: May "\text ... " be a problem? \t is tabulator. It should be `drawtext=\"\\text=` if you ask me. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/sE7w9L

Comment: Wow that was it. What's a tabulator?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`drawtext=\"\text` needs to be `drawtext=\"\\text`

See Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sE7w9L

Output:

> input.mp4 -vf drawtext="    ext='sampletext': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black: x=w-tw-10:y=h-th-10"

versus

> input.mp4 -vf drawtext="\text='sampletext': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black: x=w-tw-10:y=h-th-10"

`\t` is the escape for a tabulator (aka "[tab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key)"). That's why you need to escape the escape character itself, here. That's done by doubling it => `\\t`

---

As @Jawad correctly points out: There is another way to achieve the same goal:
"[Verbatim Identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)":

> The @ special character serves as a verbatim identifier. It can be used in the following ways:
>
> 1. To enable C# keywords to be used as identifiers.  [...]
> 2. To indicate that a string literal is to be interpreted verbatim. [...]

Example:

```
string filename1 = @"c:\documents\files\u0066.txt";
```

Comment: you can also use the @ to define string literals. `string filter = @"input.mp4 -vf drawtext=""text='samplet...`

Comment: @Jawad Absolutely. But then you'd have to change other parts of the string, too. Since OP asked "what is a tabulator", I didn't want to start confusion with yet another way to do the same thing.

Comment: I upvoted because its the correct answer. I was merely suggesting other ways as well :)

Comment: I appreciate it @Jawad

Comment: Oh I see now. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score -2):

Just before you use `args`, why not write it to the console, so you can see *exactly* what is being sent to the command line:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Args={args}");
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
```